# Android - EditText multiline forced to fill height

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, multiline, fill-parent

I need a EditText that fills in height my window.
I'm using this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_editor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</ScrollView>
```

But all I get is a one line EditText that will be longer and scrollable once I write something on multiline typing the return button.
I know I can set the line number, but in this case it should work on different devices and every device (I guess) has different amount of lines.

How can I force it to fill the device in height?

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use (without ScrollView):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_editor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: Using without scrollview did help.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting this for EditText, I had the same thing, this will work.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/text_editor"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
**android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
android:background="#ff0000"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

and you can also use this one to set exactly how many lines you need,

```
android:lines="number of Lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add it in the code it would be like this:

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
l.addView(et, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100));
```

where the `100` means it is going to have 100dp of width. the `l` is the `Layout` you may have (`ScrollView` in your case) which you can get with `R.layout.name_of_the_scroll_view`.

I'm not sure but try to put in the property of height the `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" <-----------
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text=" example text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in java code set this.....

```
ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
ed1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); <--------
```

Will work in all device.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

My Code it's Work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView20"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc1"
    android:src="@drawable/num74_head_payakorn" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPayakorn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```